# 3d effect for svg character in css animation

Tags: svg, 3d, css-animations, adobe-illustrator, keyframe

Hello i'm trying to know a bit more about SVG animations,
I think i got the grasp of how to do the basic animations with @keyframes but would like to know how to do a 3D perspective on my 2D characters that i exported in SVG with illustrator.

I linked a codepen demo of a character from rick & morty : https://codepen.io/knudsem/pen/OJyNwwM where i try to move his arm, however when i try to make a 3D effect it result in a "cardboard" effect, how would i make it to feel more realistic ?

```css
html, body {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
}

#svg-container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 100%;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.pupilles{
    animation: look-around 14s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: look-around 14s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: look-around 14s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes look-around {
        0% { transform: translate(0) }
        2% { transform: translate(3%, 1.2%) }
        4% { transform: translate(3%, 1.2%) }
        6% { transform: translate(-4.1%, -1.1%) }
        8% { transform: translate(-4.1%, -1.1%) }
        10% { transform: translate(0, 0) }
        50% { transform: translate(0, 0) }
        52% { transform: translate(3%, -2.5%) }
        54% { transform: translate(3%, -2.5%) }
        56% { transform: translate(-2.8%, 1.2%) }
        58% { transform: translate(-2.8%, 1.2%) }
        60% { transform: translate(0, 0) }
        100% { transform: translate(0, 0) }
    }

@-moz-keyframes look-around {
        0% { transform: translate(0) }
        2% { transform: translate(3%, 1.2%) }
        4% { transform: translate(3%, 1.2%) }
        6% { transform: translate(-4.1%, -1.1%) }
        8% { transform: translate(-4.1%, -1.1%) }
        10% { transform: translate(0, 0) }
        50% { transform: translate(0, 0) }
        52% { transform: translate(3%, -2.5%) }
        54% { transform: translate(3%, -2.5%) }
        56% { transform: translate(-2.8%, 1.2%) }
        58% { transform: translate(-2.8%, 1.2%) }
        60% { transform: translate(0, 0) }
        100% { transform: translate(0, 0) }
    }

 @-webkit-keyframes look-around {
        0% { transform: translate(0) }
        2% { transform: translate(3%, 1.2%) }
        4% { transform: translate(3%, 1.2%) }
        6% { transform: translate(-4.1%, -1.1%) }
        8% { transform: translate(-4.1%, -1.1%) }
        10% { transform: translate(0, 0) }
        50% { transform: translate(0, 0) }
        52% { transform: translate(3%, -2.5%) }
        54% { transform: translate(3%, -2.5%) }
        56% { transform: translate(-2.8%, 1.2%) }
        58% { transform: translate(-2.8%, 1.2%) }
        60% { transform: translate(0, 0) }
        100% { transform: translate(0, 0) }
    }
.eyes {
   transform-origin: center 38%;
    animation: blinking-size 7s infinite linear;
    animation-delay: 2s;
}
.paupiere{
    opacity: 0;
    transform-origin: center 38%;
    animation: blinking 7s infinite linear, blinking-size 7s infinite linear;
    animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes blinking {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    11%{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    12% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    13% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    15% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    18% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    19% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
   }

   @keyframes blinking-size {
     0% {
        transform: scaleY(1);
    }
    11%{
        transform: scaleY(1);
    }
    12% {
       transform: scaleY(0.2);
    }
    13% {
        transform: scaleY(1);
    }
    14% {
        transform: scaleY(1);
    }
    17% {
        transform: scaleY(1);
    }
    18% {
        transform: scaleY(0.2);
    }
    19% {
        transform: scaleY(1);
    }
    20% {
        transform: scaleY(1);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scaleY(1);
    }
   }

   @keyframes armwaving {
    50% {
          transform: scaleY(0.3) skew(10deg) perspective(400px) rotateY(5deg);
    }
    100% {
          transform: scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) perspective(0px) rotateY(0deg);
    }
   }


   #AVANT_BRAS_DROIT {
   animation: armwaving 2.5s infinite ease;
  /*-webkit-animation: armwaving 10s infinite ease;
  -moz-animation: armwaving 10s infinite ease;*/
  transform-box: fill-box;
  perspective: 400px;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
   }


   .ongles-hauts {
    animation : ongleTrois 2.5s infinite ease;
    transform-box: fill-box;;
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
   }
     .ongle-gauche {
    animation : ongleDeux 2.5s infinite ease;
    transform-box: fill-box;
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
   }


      @keyframes ongleTrois {
    50% {
          transform: translateY(45%);
    }
    100% {
          transform: translateY(0%);
    }
   }

      @keyframes ongleDeux {
    50% {
          transform: translateX(25%);
    }
    100% {
          transform: translateX(0%);
    }
   }

#effet-perspect {
    animation: perspectiveSquanch 2.5s infinite linear;
    transform-box: fill-box;
    transform-origin: 50%  10%;
}


   @keyframes perspectiveSquanch {
    0% {
      transform: scale(0);
    }
    8% {
      transform: scale(0.78);
    }
    25%{
      transform: scale(0.95);
    }
    50% {
      transform: scale(0.98);
    }
    55% {
      transform: scale(1);
    }
    85% {
      transform: scale(0);
    }
    100%{
      transform: scale(0);
    }
   }
```

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 641.27 1107.33">
        <defs>
            <style>
            .cls-1{opacity:0.52;}.cls-2{fill:#b54e21;}.cls-10,.cls-12,.cls-13,.cls-2,.cls-21,.cls-23,.cls-25,.cls-26,.cls-27,.cls-28,.cls-29,.cls-3,.cls-30,.cls-31,.cls-32,.cls-4,.cls-5,.cls-6,.cls-7,.cls-34{stroke:#000;}.cls-10,.cls-12,.cls-13,.cls-17,.cls-2,.cls-21,.cls-23,.cls-25,.cls-26,.cls-27,.cls-28,.cls-29,.cls-3,.cls-30,.cls-31,.cls-32,.cls-4,.cls-5,.cls-6,.cls-7,.cls-34{stroke-miterlimit:10;}.cls-17,.cls-2,.cls-25,.cls-26,.cls-27,.cls-29,.cls-32,.cls-4,..cls-34{stroke-width:2px;}.cls-3{fill:#d3beb0;}.cls-10,.cls-12,.cls-13,.cls-21,.cls-23,.cls-3,.cls-5,.cls-6,.cls-7{stroke-width:3px;}.cls-31,.cls-4,.cls-6{fill:none;}.cls-5,.cls-9{fill:#d9a12a;}.cls-10,.cls-8{fill:#e7daad;}.cls-11{fill:#ebdaaf;}.cls-12{fill:#c08567;}.cls-13{fill:#0ea055;}.cls-14{fill:#9b6445;}.cls-15{fill:#ad1f02;}.cls-16{fill:#d6b467;}.cls-17{fill:#edd777;stroke:#a59550;}.cls-18{fill:#ee3301;}.cls-19{fill:#f03201;}.cls-20{opacity:0.34;}.cls-21{fill:#d9a128;}.cls-22,.cls-23{fill:#eeddaf;}.cls-24{fill:#e9dda9;}.cls-25{fill:#247a8b;}.cls-26{fill:#793d47;}.cls-27{fill:#b54e23;}.cls-28,.cls-32{fill:#fff79a;}.cls-29{fill:#eb908f;}.cls-34{fill:#D9A12A;}.cls-35{stroke-width:3px;stroke:#000;stroke-miterlimit:10;fill:#ebdaaf;}.cls-77{stroke-width:3px;stroke:#000;stroke-miterlimit:10;fill:#d9a12a;}
            </style>
        </defs>
        <g id="BRAS_DROIT" data-name="BRAS DROIT">
                <g id="BRAS">
                    <path class="cls-5" d="M637.28,497.79a36.15,36.15,0,0,1-9.35,5.38c-6.13,2.28-14.72-2.54-21.45-2.52a50.77,50.77,0,0,0-26.68,7.44,11.87,11.87,0,0,1-3,1.4c-9.43,2.7-9.93,2.88-14.36,2.13a12.73,12.73,0,0,1-2.27-.63c-7.09-2.78-24.39-7.86-33.48-7.86a11.52,11.52,0,0,1-7.67-2.91c-8.61-7.67-10.92-10.77-13.84-15.37-3.32-5.22-8.09-41.4-46.57-37.21l-9.11,56c1.11-1.33,12.51-3.43,14.14,2.54s12.22,21,23.76,35c10.9,13.24,32.35,11.7,42.69,12.6a11.55,11.55,0,0,0,3.61-.26c9.56-2.18,21.42-3.7,34.18,5.55,13.33,9.67,47.9-6.92,70.41-2.2a10.75,10.75,0,0,0,2.88.27c.68,0,1.34-.12,2-.19" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                    <path class="cls-6" d="M641.92,556.6C625,554,607,559,590,562c-12,2-23-3-34-8-9-3-18-2-27,0a62.52,62.52,0,0,1-30-4c-15-6-21-22-31-34-3-4-3-10-7-13-4-2-8-2-11.55.6" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                    <path class="cls-6" d="M458.56,447.64C469,444,479,449,487,455c11,7,14,20,20,32,3.67,6.42,8.73,13.3,15,15.7a8.19,8.19,0,0,0,3.26.45C548.78,502,553.31,513,568,511c17.22-2,30.59-15.77,48.35-8.43" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g id="AVANT_BRAS_DROIT" data-name="AVANT BRAS DROIT">
                <g id="AVANT_BRAS_DROIT-2" data-name="AVANT BRAS DROIT">
                    <g id="effet-perspect"><path class="cls-35" d="M625.73,605.87V594.74l-.33-20.66,1.67-26s1.52.92,9.24-7.6,12.26-13.25,12.09-35.74-.53-33.79-5.74-40.86-21.27-20.42-60.09-1c-33.89,17-35.87,29.51-33,33.4,0,0,9.89,6.1,10.28-1.13,0,0,6-21,22.55-20.94s40.92-3.15,48.36,5.46,8.57,29,8.39,31.6-4.89,25-16.37,32.44c0,0-7.74.82-5,18.77,0,0,1,35.5.3,42.87" transform="translate(0 0)"/><path class="cls-77" d="M625.73,605.87v20.65s1,26.71-9.91,42.16-4.73,3.31-4.73,3.31c6.39-11.36,6.33-59.26,7-66.64" transform="translate(0 0)"/></g>
                    <path class="cls-5" d="M617.32,556.85c7.79-2.38,22.83.34,23.8.28,26.15-1.68,33.69-27.4,38.2-38.08a11.25,11.25,0,0,0,.89-4.54c-.1-10.79-.67-43.45,2-52.23A48,48,0,0,0,683,452.2c-1.92-12.89,0-33.59-.76-48.73A11.35,11.35,0,0,1,688,393.26c1.56-.95,2.56-2.59,4.7-4.61a24.06,24.06,0,0,0,6.33-9.71c8.17-24,1.56-45.84-1.49-49.66-7.83-10.83-42.14-8-50-7.26a10.77,10.77,0,0,1-2.72-.11c-3-.48-11.86.18-19.33,20.88l-.15.44c-.6,1.87-4.62,15.66,2.23,35.28a11.8,11.8,0,0,0,2,3.63c2.93,3.55,7,8.59,13,10.73a11.45,11.45,0,0,1,7.43,9.36,28.56,28.56,0,0,1-.92,13.62c-3,8.75-10.1,26.31-13.68,28-1.2.55-1.41,1.17-1.16,1.74a10.84,10.84,0,0,1,.35,6.87c-.77,3.19-1.44,8.51-1.44,17.35,0,20-5.06,35.08-10.67,34.18" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                    <path class="cls-8 d300" d="M676.13,458.21c-5.18-3.2-6.75-26.23-7-23-1.28,14.94-3.49,26.13-8.94,23.75s-6.89-20.08-6.89-20.08-6.13,4.42-10.22,16.33-8.43-2.81-8.43-2.81a10.84,10.84,0,0,0-.35-6.87c-.25-.57,0-1.19,1.16-1.74,3.58-1.65,10.69-19.21,13.68-28a28.56,28.56,0,0,0,.92-13.62,11.45,11.45,0,0,0-7.43-9.36c-6.06-2.14-10.1-7.18-13-10.73a11.8,11.8,0,0,1-2-3.63c-6.85-19.62-2.83-33.41-2.23-35.28l.15-.44c7.47-20.7,16.28-21.36,19.33-20.88a10.77,10.77,0,0,0,2.72.11c7.86-.79,42.17-3.57,50,7.26,3.05,3.82,9.66,25.69,1.49,49.66a24.06,24.06,0,0,1-6.33,9.71c-2.14,2-3.14,3.66-4.7,4.61a11.35,11.35,0,0,0-5.71,10.21c.72,15.14-1.16,35.84.76,48.73C683,452.2,681.57,461.57,676.13,458.21Z" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                    <path class="cls-6" d="M617.32,556.85C619,557,620,556,622,556c10-1,19,3,29-1,17-6,24-23,29-38,0-21-1-42,3-62-1-17-2-34-1-51a11.35,11.35,0,0,1,3-8c20-15,22-42,15-63-4-10-14-10-23-12-12-1-23,1-35,1-20,9-22,37-15,55a29.82,29.82,0,0,0,17,16c8,4,8,14,6,22-1,2-3,4-3,6-2,9-7,16-12,24-1,2,0,5,0,8-3,14-1,27-4,41-1,4-3,8-7.08,9.85" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                </g>
                <path class="cls-5" d="M641.12,557.13" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                <g class="ongle-gauche">
                    <path class="cls-7" d="M621.38,353.07s-12.14-12-14.38-18.34,9.21,6.93,21.34,1.78C624.64,344.13,621.38,353.07,621.38,353.07Z" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                </g>
                    <g class="ongles-hauts">
                    <path class="cls-7" d="M641,320.88s1.14-19.79,2.76-22.09,7.36,6.72,7,22.28C641.08,319.68,641,320.88,641,320.88Z" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                    <path class="cls-7" d="M666,320.12c-.28-2.15-1.48-14,4.67-22.65a.44.44,0,0,1,.69,0c3,3.54,6,14,3.06,23.3a.42.42,0,0,1-.44.3l-7.59-.56A.44.44,0,0,1,666,320.12Z" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                    <path class="cls-7" d="M688.37,323.61s.94-15.5,7.17-21.35c.46-.43,1.75-1.74,2.19-1.28,1.8,1.86,3.46,7.27-3,25.21Z" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                    </g>
            </g>
            <g id="CORPS"><path class="cls-9" d="M300.57,420.9l-28.11,67.83,11.16,23.53,8.08,14.59,13.51,35.24s9.59,63.81,9.56,70.58S307.94,677,307.94,677L408.51,793.62l24.59-12.13s11.85-18.55,10.71-24,7.47-30.26,7.47-30.26L457.82,685s4.12-9.28-7.19-26.51c-1.79-8.68-3.65-8.68-5.58-35.69,3.2-24.29,16.89-15-4.8-61.46-1.8-13.07-4.35-14.91,3.56-31.36S461,506.17,458,451.79s-35.22-30.89-35.22-30.89Z" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                <path class="cls-5" d="M456.51,469.77c5.82,26.87-9.14,58.28-14.91,69.05a18,18,0,0,0-2.13,8c-.15,4.76-.23,11.1,5.59,22.74,5.83,11.18,12.58,24.51,1.77,49.4a15.84,15.84,0,0,0-1.18,7.64c.66,8.09-2.69,12.67,11.16,43,2.55,5.11,5.59,26.55-8.69,48.51,0,6.13-3,10.72,1.08,32.68,0,0,3.52,23.14-8.52,31.34-59.25,40.34-140.4,8.48-140.4,8.48s-24.37-20.88-33.64-28.6c-28.88-24-18.09-44.43-15.56-51.18,5.41-10.93,9.1-7.32,9.81-12.46a19.86,19.86,0,0,0-3.29-13.71c-13.93-21,5.34-37,12.86-48.29,11.49-10.69,11.42-13.74,11.45-18.78a29.65,29.65,0,0,0-4.15-15c-5.63-9.79,1.94-16.91,5.27-19.71,5.73-5,7.34-8.19,8-11.12a16.09,16.09,0,0,0-3.51-13.57c-2.79-3.45-5.47-6.92-7.72-10.18a24.12,24.12,0,0,1-4-18.61,58.68,58.68,0,0,0,1.1-10.49s-3.92-10.9,0-17.33" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/><path class="cls-10" d="M329.19,452.51S318,466.13,312.85,504.6c8.85-6.47,12.26-9.54,16.34-9.54,1,3.41-8.17,10.22-4.08,36.77l8.17-8.85s3.4,25.87-4.09,41.19-21.45,27.57-1,60.94c2.72,8.51,6.47,11.23-11.23,54.12-1.37,4.09-6.72,27.92,6.51,67.07,6.76,10.21,13.57,17.7,17,20.76,0-6.8-3.07-19.06,0-17.7s9.53,21.79,21.1,23.49c3.41-5.79,8.17-21.11,8.17-21.11s3.07-2,5.79,4.43,3.74,11.92,6.81,9.53,20.76-23.83,23.15-47.66-2.73-32,0-48.68,4.37-20.76.65-37.1-16.65-36.77-5.42-65.71c3.06-9.53,4.6-24.85,4.68-38.81,4.85,3.75,7.15,7.49,9.06,5.79-.12-11.23.22-24.85-1.82-34.72-1.66-1.36,1.7-3.41,4.76-1s7.3,5.33,8.85,8.17a7.14,7.14,0,0,1,1,3.06c-2.38-14.64,0-45.62-5.44-52.08S329.19,452.51,329.19,452.51Z" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                <path class="cls-6" d="M358.9,522s-3.84,69.78,5,55.83,8.86-20.09,8.86-20.09-.22,21.79,5.91,25.53" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                <g id="Calque_10" data-name="Calque 10">
                    <path class="cls-6" d="M456.51,469.77c5.82,26.87-9.14,58.28-14.91,69.05a18,18,0,0,0-2.13,8c-.15,4.76-.23,11.1,5.59,22.74,5.83,11.18,12.58,24.51,1.77,49.4a15.84,15.84,0,0,0-1.18,7.64c.66,8.09-2.69,12.67,11.16,43,2.55,5.11,5.59,26.55-8.69,48.51,0,6.13-3,10.72,1.08,32.68,0,0,3.52,23.14-8.52,31.34-59.25,40.34-140.4,8.48-140.4,8.48s-24.37-20.88-33.64-28.6c-28.88-24-18.09-44.43-15.56-51.18,5.41-10.93,9.1-7.32,9.81-12.46a19.86,19.86,0,0,0-3.29-13.71c-13.93-21,5.34-37,12.86-48.29,11.49-10.69,11.42-13.74,11.45-18.78a29.65,29.65,0,0,0-4.15-15c-5.63-9.79,1.94-16.91,5.27-19.71,5.73-5,7.34-8.19,8-11.12a16.09,16.09,0,0,0-3.51-13.57c-2.79-3.45-5.47-6.92-7.72-10.18a24.12,24.12,0,0,1-4-18.61,58.68,58.68,0,0,0,1.1-10.49s-3.92-10.9,0-17.33" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                </g>
            </g>
                            <g id="TËTE">
                                <path class="cls-21" d="M493.35,109.22s-9.19,9-10.15,17.54c16-10.43,53.92-26.06,108.28-26,10.63-3,27.14-4.82,37-13.08-3.66,9.8-29,36.35-38,49.13s-25.86,29.49-45.43,37.82c3.63,1.36,11.65,3.78,19.77-.5-11.12,10-32.78,27.89-32.51,39.83,2.49,1.29,4.91,4.06,15.84,4.81-3.38,3.12-9.58,12-21.53,17.88S445.84,231,445.84,231l-16.08-63.66S445.72,124.92,493.35,109.22Z" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                                <path class="cls-22" d="M521.23,148.71s13.68,5-3.35,18.1c.48,1.3-2.26,1.89,3.71.86s18.91-5.45-.19,15.2c-6.47,4.68-12.24,8.73-9.82,15.38,1.38.65,10.53,4.34.37,9.46a131.37,131.37,0,0,1-18.68,7.79L497.79,182l-.35-14.4Z" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                                <path class="cls-22" d="M528.48,139.23a50.17,50.17,0,0,1-24.94,16,24.35,24.35,0,0,0-9.31,4.81c-5.63,4.77-12.21,10-14,21.62a9.08,9.08,0,0,1-2.18,4.7c-4.58,5.07-5.42,7.24-11.6,10.42,3.19,2,17,4.38,28.89.43-5.14,7.23-9.32,17.05-7.69,18.44s6.07-.09,13.25-2.92" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                                <path class="cls-21" d="M253.85,135.94s9.45,7.09,11.36,14.69c-15.8-7.52-52.17-17.07-101.54-10.4-10-1.41-25.24-1.06-35.22-7.35,4.52,8.45,30.73,29.48,40.54,40s27.1,23.62,45.89,28.8c-3.13,1.68-10.13,4.86-18,2,11.33,7.75,33.19,21.33,34.4,32.2-2.1,1.48-4,4.29-13.8,6.31,3.46,2.42,10.17,9.73,21.74,13.61s72.69-14.95,72.69-14.95L318.72,181S299,144.38,253.85,135.94Z" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                                <path class="cls-22" d="M209.42,161.58s-10.57,7.74,7.39,14.82c-.09,1.23,2.42,1.07-3,1.66s-17.7,0,3.94,13.09c6.75,2.43,12.74,4.5,12.31,10.85-1,.91-8,6.37,2,8.27a118.88,118.88,0,0,0,18.08,2.09L238,184.56,234.68,172Z" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                                <path class="cls-22" d="M200.81,155.19a45.09,45.09,0,0,0,25.53,7.65,21.83,21.83,0,0,1,9.23,1.84c6.05,2.72,13,5.58,17.45,15.21a8.17,8.17,0,0,0,3.06,3.52c5.22,3.25,6.48,4.91,12.61,6.13-2.26,2.55-13.64,8-24.86,7.54,6.23,5,12.28,12.42,11.22,14s-5.26,1.43-12.18.77" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                                <path d="M200.81,155.19a46.08,46.08,0,0,0,18.39,6.58,44,44,0,0,0,4.86.39h2.45a24.15,24.15,0,0,1,2.55.09,22.16,22.16,0,0,1,5,1,23.83,23.83,0,0,1,2.37.93c.76.32,1.52.65,2.28,1a33.37,33.37,0,0,1,8.62,5.31,25.92,25.92,0,0,1,6.15,8.14,15.22,15.22,0,0,0,1.11,2,6.9,6.9,0,0,0,1.5,1.55c.53.4,1.35.86,2,1.31l2.07,1.37a24.18,24.18,0,0,0,4.13,2.36,24.47,24.47,0,0,0,4.56,1.33l1.72.35-1.18,1.24a12.66,12.66,0,0,1-2.89,2.15,31.06,31.06,0,0,1-3,1.55,45,45,0,0,1-6.35,2.29,43.6,43.6,0,0,1-6.59,1.38,41.17,41.17,0,0,1-6.75.27l.49-1.31A55.46,55.46,0,0,1,250,201.9a35.76,35.76,0,0,1,4.74,6.24,7.25,7.25,0,0,1,.79,1.89,1.65,1.65,0,0,1-.09,1.22,2.07,2.07,0,0,1-.86.76,8.9,8.9,0,0,1-3.94.59,73.58,73.58,0,0,1-7.72-.72c2.58.14,5.16.31,7.71.23a8.46,8.46,0,0,0,3.61-.7,1.57,1.57,0,0,0,.56-.52,1.14,1.14,0,0,0,0-.67,6.73,6.73,0,0,0-.79-1.62,38,38,0,0,0-4.85-5.86,60.84,60.84,0,0,0-5.7-5.08l-1.73-1.35,2.22,0a41.8,41.8,0,0,0,12.79-1.88,46.61,46.61,0,0,0,6.06-2.3c1-.47,1.93-.95,2.84-1.49A11.08,11.08,0,0,0,268,188.9l.54,1.59a26.34,26.34,0,0,1-4.94-1.42,25.15,25.15,0,0,1-4.47-2.51l-4.19-2.76a9.06,9.06,0,0,1-1.91-2,16.67,16.67,0,0,1-1.25-2.31,24.91,24.91,0,0,0-5.64-7.61,31.38,31.38,0,0,0-8.1-5.16c-1.48-.69-3-1.46-4.44-2a21.52,21.52,0,0,0-4.65-1.07,23.76,23.76,0,0,0-2.39-.14l-2.51-.09a43.92,43.92,0,0,1-5-.59,45.34,45.34,0,0,1-9.57-2.81A39.63,39.63,0,0,1,200.81,155.19Z" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                                <path class="cls-5" d="M282.45,234.5s-3.09-35.34,14.71-40c3.88-3.93,17.88-11.91,10.53-27.39s-14-34.45-8.14-43c5.18,8.32,14.79,18.33,21.78,17.42-1.86-5.88-9.71-69.43,8.93-85.25,4.74,5.28,1.44,24.73,8,21.29,7.75-10.46,23-25.06,33.44-75.69,6.85-30.08,13.87-46.64,19-54.48.56,10.31,3.5,34.73,18.68,27.44C421.18-39,425-46.08,427.54-66.42s1.15-47.68,34.83-79.1c1.92,22,3.7,35.73-5.69,58.51-1.46,8.12,10.4-2.66,15.77-9.5,1,7.41,14.21,21.19-51.36,132.18a74.74,74.74,0,0,0-9.36,24.57,58.47,58.47,0,0,0,.2,23c6.29-2.34,22.58-9.33,33.12-24-1.54,12.82,8,39-11.26,67,7.1-.94,13.87-8.59,16.46-11.21s2.25,8.4-8.65,28.89c-4,11.24-10.81,23.52-3.68,35.39,7.89,2.84,27.26,10.85,22.4,37.91s-34.78,107.25-34.78,107.25l-141,4Z" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                                <path class="cls-23" d="M348.36,311.65s-6.36-18.26-53-6.71L261.3,286.29s3.66,20.33-16.45,29c-4.23-.29-22-.8-25.58-5.28-3-3.83-1.9,14.29.64,23.77a13.1,13.1,0,0,1-.65,8.73c-2.38,5.28-7.42,11.78-24.72,7,1.88,4.65,5,19.14,14.58,31.37a10.81,10.81,0,0,1,1.29,11.62c-1.35,2.59-3.78,5.14-11.31,9.15a1.43,1.43,0,0,0-.22,2.4c10.44,8.09,37.56,27.12,48.92,34.6,8,14.2,13.94,44.89,62.07,27.84a12.4,12.4,0,0,1,6-.55c11.31,1.83,24.67,4.44,30.08,11.11a13.6,13.6,0,0,0,4.22,3.59c10.69,5.65,31.47,16.24,61.22-17.63a11,11,0,0,1,7.56-3.79c8.31-.55,19.1-.26,19.1-.26s29.58,9.68,47.28-32.84a17.78,17.78,0,0,1,5.35-7,36.42,36.42,0,0,1,12.81-6.93c8.4-2.25,38.65-11.08,43.28-24-5.13-4.68-13-6.19-13.53-11.3s21.09-10.26,21.6-28.09c-4.42-1.18-21.84,1.56-26.22-12.14C530.84,332,537,324,536,309c-6.1.74-35.24,1-49.27-19.06S407,300.12,407,300.12s-36.37,12.17-42.2,9.72S348.36,311.65,348.36,311.65Z" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                                <path class="cls-4" d="M354.42,355.4s-9.21-23.11,3.18-37.48" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                                <path class="cls-24" d="M349.69,173.18s-2.7,46.1,16,60.92c5.21,1.1,11.5,1.21,20.59-23.34,5.27-12.29,10.87-20.45,8.57-26.53S378,200.6,378,200.6s9.8-24.38,4-35.88-17.86,27.2-17.86,27.2S356.46,165.42,349.69,173.18Z" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                                <path class="cls-25" d="M337.85,313.81c6.23,5.66,20.7,14.8,38.47-.28a5.36,5.36,0,0,0,1.41-6.35c-5-10.74-22.93-26.49-40.73-.7A5.62,5.62,0,0,0,337.85,313.81Z" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                                <path class="cls-6" d="M493.65,343.82l29.57-13.38,18.67-8.71a22.06,22.06,0,0,0,2.52-1.39l6.29-4a6,6,0,0,1,6.47,0l8.63,5.43a11,11,0,0,0,9.45,1.11c5.18-1.79,12.85-6.15,18.54-16.77" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                                <path class="cls-6" d="M492.58,369.06s36.51-4.59,66.83-11.56a13.65,13.65,0,0,1,6.1,0c4.55,1,9.28,2.57,11.31,21.8a2.17,2.17,0,0,0,2.92,1.8c7.9-2.94,26.31-6.5,28.7-3.79" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                                <path class="cls-6" d="M484.56,385.83s-5.72,9.16,8.79,14.68a35.18,35.18,0,0,0,14.91,2.11c6.64-.45,13.22,0,12.51,12.26.31,6.13-3.88,14.06,11.11,7.36a18.5,18.5,0,0,1,18,1.43c3.94,2.68,8,7.3,11.32,15.23" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                                <path class="cls-6" d="M239.8,331.33S225.64,303,209.56,311s-14.57,10.29-21.33.22c-4.91-7.32-7.3-17.07-8.24-21.87a4.41,4.41,0,0,0-5.67-3.4,20.67,20.67,0,0,0-4.84,2.53c-7.79,5.25-25.79,14-31.33,4.82" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                                <path class="cls-6" d="M229.84,359s-29.91,3.48-48,11.34a34.27,34.27,0,0,1-7.65,2.38c-3,.54-6.13.25-8.67-11.17a53.54,53.54,0,0,1-1.16-11.71c0-7.92-3.2-18.87-29.11-4.75-10.92,5.7-19.18,12.17-24.45,18.1a2.35,2.35,0,0,1-4-1c-.52-2.28-.94-4.38-1.27-6.14a7.85,7.85,0,0,0-8.17-6.45,12,12,0,0,0-5.85,1.89,58.26,58.26,0,0,1-7.6,4.32c-7.12,3.25-16.77,8-19.13,6.42" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                                <path class="cls-6" d="M230.74,376s-26.5,25.78-39.73,24.85-22.22.92-32.16,16c-3.48,3.32-16.93,16.51-27,13.36" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                                <path class="cls-26" d="M274.83,344.5s-24,2.87-8,23.7a5.37,5.37,0,0,0,.5.57c16,15.43,48.24,32,48.24,32S348.76,422.61,444.06,379c9.69-6.16,40.3-29.66-3.13-33-11.88-.74-43.67,1.48-69.2,8.78a37.23,37.23,0,0,1-11.3,1.48,63.24,63.24,0,0,1-18.15-3.27C332.85,350.29,285.48,343,274.83,344.5Z" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                                <path class="cls-4" d="M315.07,415.12s15,18.11,79.81-1.47" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                                <path class="cls-27" d="M340.16,422.69s-1.93,20.72,2.56,26.57a2.56,2.56,0,0,0,4.08-.08c1.17-1.6,2-4.45,2.62-10.89.08-1.28-.1-2.64,1.24-.23a26.67,26.67,0,0,1,2.24,5.28c.38,1.23.67,2.25.89,3.05a10.71,10.71,0,0,0,3.45,5.48c2.79,2.3,7.05,3.78,9.88-4.62.54-2.46,3-8.3,8.08-.62,1.54,2.42,8.64,8.39,9.46-6A229.43,229.43,0,0,0,383.05,417S360.43,423.52,340.16,422.69Z" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                                <path class="cls-28" d="M327.5,350.81s-.09,20,4.75,31.23a1.15,1.15,0,0,0,2.11,0l10.87-26.95Z" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                                <path class="cls-28" d="M292.23,345.59s.78,12.69,3.46,17.19a2.54,2.54,0,0,0,3.6.74c3.2-2.18,7-6.38,9.65-15.8C307.34,347.48,292.23,345.59,292.23,345.59Z" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                                <path class="cls-28" d="M390.19,351.57s4.8,17.81,18.05,27.34c.67-.14,3.48-12.64-.11-30.09C405.86,349.1,392.93,350.1,390.19,351.57Z" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                                <path class="cls-28" d="M410.85,348.5s6,27.86,10.62,23.78,10.94-24,10.9-25.33C431.89,346.66,416.48,347.89,410.85,348.5Z" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                                <path class="cls-29" d="M349.15,406.13s-.58-17.19,23.52-20.93c7.43-.31,23.11-2.28,32.09,9.5C401.35,395.81,371.25,405.2,349.15,406.13Z" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                                <circle class="cls-30" cx="242.31" cy="469.26" r="2.8"/>
                                <circle class="cls-30" cx="235.32" cy="484" r="1.36"/>
                                <circle class="cls-30" cx="222.72" cy="473.28" r="2.8"/>
                                <circle cx="337.79" cy="468.85" r="1.72"/>
                                <circle class="cls-30" cx="336.31" cy="483.49" r="2.55"/>
                                <circle class="cls-30" cx="359.37" cy="473.33" r="2.75"/>
                                <path class="cls-31" d="M347.3,307.35s2.9,12.69,6.82,14.28c.65-4.17,6.64-13.91,8.11-14.39" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"/>
                            </g>
                                <g class="eyes" id="GLOBE_GAUCHE" data-name="GLOBE GAUCHE">
                                    <path class="cls-32" d="M298.37,210.19a39.52,39.52,0,0,0-18.46,7.23c-13.18,9.52-37,30.1-31.86,51.4,2.06,8.63,4.47,28,28.41,36.54a56.76,56.76,0,0,0,52.73-8.23,58.12,58.12,0,0,0,23.45-38.34,39.45,39.45,0,0,0-.5-15.94C348.79,229.24,337.62,205.53,298.37,210.19Z" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"> 
                                    </path>
                                </g>
                                <g class="pupilles" id="PUPILLE_GAUCHE" data-name="PUPILLE GAUCHE">
                                    <path class="cls-30" d="M281.69,266.67s-1.81-13.91,3.65-2.52c3.85-1.57,13.76-7.9,7.61.2,1.37,1.6,8.89,2.93-.84,4.93.48,2.24,6,10-3.41,4.87-1.9-.39-4,9.57-5.66-.92C282.63,271.22,272.29,270.37,281.69,266.67Z" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"> 
                                    </path>
                                </g>
                                <g class="paupiere" id="pop" data-name="paupiere">
                                    <path class="cls-34" d="M298.37,210.19a39.52,39.52,0,0,0-18.46,7.23c-13.18,9.52-37,30.1-31.86,51.4,2.06,8.63,4.47,28,28.41,36.54a56.76,56.76,0,0,0,52.73-8.23,58.12,58.12,0,0,0,23.45-38.34,39.45,39.45,0,0,0-.5-15.94C348.79,229.24,337.62,205.53,298.37,210.19Z" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"> 
                                    </path>
                                </g>
                                <g class="eyes" id="GLOBE_DROIT" data-name="GLOBE DROIT">
                                    <path class="cls-32" d="M434.11,207.73A39.52,39.52,0,0,0,415.65,215c-13.18,9.52-37,30.1-31.86,51.4,2.06,8.63,4.47,28,28.41,36.54a56.76,56.76,0,0,0,52.73-8.23,58.12,58.12,0,0,0,23.45-38.34,39.63,39.63,0,0,0-.5-15.94C484.53,226.78,473.35,203.07,434.11,207.73Z" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"> 
                                    </path>
                                </g>

                                <g class="pupilles" id="PUPILLE_DROIT" data-name="PUPILLE DROIT">
                                    <path class="cls-30" d="M450.29,260.72s8.59-12.71-4.63-4.78c-1.06-1.35-5-7.78-5.28-.32-1,2.91-15.65,1.23-1.35,7.42.61,1.7-5.82,5.89,2.28,4.74.91,1.9,2.19,6.85,5.92.87C450.32,265.93,457.76,268.9,450.29,260.72Z" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)">  
                                    </path>
                                </g>
                                <g class="paupiere" id="pop" data-name="paupiere">
                                    <path class="cls-34" d="M434.11,207.73A39.52,39.52,0,0,0,415.65,215c-13.18,9.52-37,30.1-31.86,51.4,2.06,8.63,4.47,28,28.41,36.54a56.76,56.76,0,0,0,52.73-8.23,58.12,58.12,0,0,0,23.45-38.34,39.63,39.63,0,0,0-.5-15.94C484.53,226.78,473.35,203.07,434.11,207.73Z" transform="translate(-63.9 148.72)"> 
                                    </path>
                                </g>
                            </svg>
```